# Google Api default credential

Tags: oauth, google-api, xamarin.android, google-cloud-vision

I am trying to make one simple application in Xamrin android using
[Google Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/).

What I did is,

Installed

1. Google cloud vision v1,
2. Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
3. Newtonsoft.Json;

in my xamarin.android project from NuGet manager.

I created

1. API Key,
2. Service Account,
3. OAuth 2.0 client IDs

from google cloud console.

I created GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS (Environmenta variable) 
and linked those Json file (both service account and
OAuth 2.0 client IDs json) tried both.

Then I just copied code from google vision API documentaion.

```
// Load an image from a local file.
var image = Image.FromFile(filePath);
var client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create();
var response = client.DetectLogos(image);
foreach (var annotation in response)
{
if (annotation.Description != null)
    textView.Text = (annotation.Description);
}
```

everytime i try to compile the program it throws exception

> > System.InvalidOperationException: The Application Default 
> >     Credentials are not available. They are available if 
> >     running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, 
> >     the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS 
> >     must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. 
> >     See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/
> >     application-default-credentials for more information.

I need help to set default credentials, I tried many links from google
documentation but no luck.
has anyone got any idea how to handle this exception.

Comment: what line fails and where are you creating client?

Comment: @DalmTo It stops on the 
var client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create();

Comment: `Google.Cloud.Vision.V1` is a gRPC-based library - even if you got past the authentication, I wouldn't expect it to work on Xamarin at the moment. Xamarin isn't a supported platform for this code, and most importantly gRPC needs a native library which is only built on x86 and x64 at the moment.

Comment: (It's not clear why you've added the google-app-engine tag here, either - I can't see that AppEngine is really involved here at all...)

Comment: @Jon Skeet Yes, your point is right, I will remove tag. Thanks for your information about xamarin support for vision api. At first, I tried it in console application and got output, so thought I can work with it in Xamarin as well.

Comment: We hope to support Xamarin at *some* point, but we don't right now.

Comment: @JonSkeet 

so at the moment I can't use Google.Cloud.Vision.V1 in my xamarin project. is there any alternative way to work with this api in Xamarin.

Comment: @KopilaPanth: You could use the REST API: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Vision.v1/

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you for valuable information. Appreciated. I will search how to implement it using REST API.

Comment: @JonSkeet I could not find proper documentation how to work with the REST API you mentioned, could you recommend some links to me to start with that.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't think we have samples for it, as the gRPC-based libraries are expected to be the more common route, but https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate should be your starting point. See https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started for general guidance on using the REST APIs.